# Promise running setTimeout in then asynchronously

Tags: javascript

I am returning a Promise in an IFFE and the first thing that gets logged is `first` but then immediately after that `third` is logged and then comes `second`.  If my setTimeout is in the `then`, isn't everything in there synchronously run?

```
(() => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
       console.log("first")
       resolve()
    })
    .then(() => {
       setTimeout(() => console.log("second"), 3000)
    })


})()
.then(() => console.log("third"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `setTimeout` in a Promise-based way you have to create another promise there and resolve it in the `setTimeout` callback like so:

```
new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 3000));
```

Or in context:

```
new Promise(resolve => {
  console.log('first');
  resolve();
})
  .then(
    () =>
      new Promise(resolve =>
        setTimeout(() => {
          console.log('second');
          resolve();
        }, 3000)
      )
  )
  .then(() => console.log('third'));
```

Comment: I don't have to `return` the `new Promise` ?

Comment: The arrow function implicitly returns it. See https://jaketrent.com/post/javascript-arrow-function-return-rules/